# What Riak client does the Doctrine Cache Riak Provider use?

Tags: php, caching, doctrine, riak

I have been working with [Doctrine Cache](https://github.com/doctrine/cache), and wanted to try the Riak provider:

```
// host: localhost, port: 8098
$client = new \Basho\Riak\Riak($app['host'], $app['port']); 
$bucket = $client->bucket('key_value');
$cacheProvider = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\RiakCache($bucket);
```

In the code I created a client as described in the [Basho official PHP Client for Riak](https://github.com/basho/riak-php-client) (also see [Taste of Riak: PHP](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/taste-of-riak/php/)), and passed the bucket as required by the Riak Cache Provider and got the following error:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to 
Doctrine\\Common\\Cache\\RiakCache::__construct() 
must be an instance of Riak\\Bucket, 
instance of Basho\\Riak\\Bucket given.
```

This error message and the [unit test for the Riak provider](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/tests/Doctrine/Tests/Common/Cache/RiakCacheTest.php#L37) point to a different client, but the doctrine documentation [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/caching.html) doesn't say anything about Riak.

I don't know if the provider used by the Doctrine Cache is an old version of the Official Riak PHP Client, if there is a problem with the code, or if the provider uses a different Riak Client Like the [Doctrine riak-php](https://github.com/doctrine/riak-php) which is experimental and has no documentation on how to install and use it (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine cache does not use the default basho client, but uses the `php_riak` extension.
See more:

http://pecl.php.net/package/riak

https://github.com/php-riak/php_riak